# What are the possible use-case for tableau and hadoop integration

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, tableau-api

I would like to do analytics on data present on hadoop. how can we connect from tableau to hadoop?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? Have you googled "tableau hadoop"? Open ended questions are not really what SO is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario-1:** From tableau desktop user can connect to Hiveserver or Hiveserver2 it have connectors. There is no ODBC drivers available as of now for connecting to Apache Hive directly from tableau.

**Scenario-2:** Cloudera provides ODBC drivers for tableau integration with hadoop via cloudera hive server.
 http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/odbc/2-5-20.html

Hope these information will help!!